Is there a way to write a file locally using Airflow?
I'm using airflow for a project, and I'm a beginner. I'm looking to write a file locally.
I tried that (here is my DAG) :

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def write_simple_file(**kwargs):
    file_path = '/Users/paul/airflow/output/hello_airflow.txt'
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write("Hello from Airflow DAG!\n")
    print(f"File written to {file_path}")

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'write_file_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='DAG pour écrire un fichier simple',
    schedule_interval=None,  
    start_date=datetime(2024, 5, 7),
    catchup=False,
)

write_file_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='write_file_task',
    python_callable=write_simple_file,
    dag=dag,
)

write_file_task


but I got a No such file directory error in the logs.

if you are running Airflow in docker then by default the docker container running your DAG will see a folder structure like this /opt/airflow i.e. it will not be able to access your laptop/mac home folder. You could scp or sftp the file to your home folder using Python logic or the airflow SFTP operator.

perhaps a volume mount is the answer

if you are running Airflow in docker then by default the docker container running your DAG will see a folder structure like this /opt/airflow i.e. it will not be able to access your laptop/mac home folder. You could scp or sftp the file to your home folder using Python logic.

Ok it works thanks for your answers! However, I have a bug that has just appeared, I made a small script to convert the .tsv into .parquet, and when I launch the corresponding DAG, I have:
ERROR - Detected zombie job: {'full_filepath': '/opt/airflow/dags/formatting_data.py', 'processor_subdir': '/opt/airflow/dags', 'msg': "{'DAG Id': 'formatting_data', 'Task Id': 'format_imdb_data', 'Run Id': 'scheduled__2024-05-11T00:00:00+00:00', 'Hostname': 'dd0bbc46b6fa'}", 'simple_task_instance': <airflow.models.taskinstance.SimpleTaskInstance object at 0xffff937ba850>, 'is_failure_callback': True}

I would suggest to pls accept the answer if it solved your original issue and ask a new question.
